# Javascript setting date for mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to set my Date object in javascript, but I keep getting wrong date. This is how I set

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth();
var day = today.getDate();
var hour = today.getHours();
var minute = today.getMinutes();
var second = today.getSeconds();

var create_date = new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0).toISOString();
```

My local datetime is 2015-11-17 21:00:00, however this creates 2015-11-16 22:00:00.000Z. If I use hour, minute and second variables in date constructor it creates the correct time in mongodb. I want to set date as 2015-11-17 00:00:00. What might be the problem?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Even the date is set correct in javascript, date in mongo db is seen as 2015-11-16 22:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the date to the start of today, use the **[`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)** method of the Date object as follows:

```
var create_date = new Date();
create_date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(create_date); // prints Tue Nov 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

For UTC, use **[`setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours)**:

```
create_date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: My document's date in mongodb is seen as 2015-11-16 22:00:00.000Z. However, console print is true. Why can't I just enter the same date into mongodb?

Comment: Try `create_date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);`